# the value is undefined and applying a check in the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

the issue i am having is the slice is undefined - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
how can i write a code to use if the value is not defined or error, just use `$("#x").val().slice(3,5)`

tried like this but seems not working

```
w = (typeof x.val() !== 'undefined') ? $("#x").val().slice(3,5)  : 0;
```

Comment: Is it `x` or `$("#x")`? Are they the same?

Comment: Please clarify where `x` is defined as this appears to be a variable where as `$("#x")` is a jQuery Object. Based on your example, we cannot determine if `x` is the same as `$("#x")`. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You may also want to look at try...catch: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.val()` and `$("#x").val()` are very different things, unless it just happens that `x` is the result of a previous call to `$("#x")`.

The only time jQuery's `val` returns `undefined` is if you call it on an empty set (which would mean there is no element with `id="x"` in the DOM when you do `$("#x")`). The simple way to do this is to grab the value, then do the check:

```
const val = x.val(); // Or `= $("#x").val()`, whatever is the one you actually want
w = typeof val !== "undefined" ? val.slice(3,5) : 0;
```

Beware, though, that you're assigning a string to `w` in one case but a number in the other. Typically you're best off being consistent, either always use a string, or always use a number.

Comment: can i use `$('#x').val()` in `const val = $('#x').val()`

Comment: @Notion - Yes, see the comment on that line of code above.

Comment: `w = typeof $("#x").val() !== "undefined" ? val.slice(3,5) : 0;`

Comment: @Notion - Why would you do that? Why not reuse the `val` constant? That's the whole point of saving the result to `val`.

Comment: just to be on one single line and making sure it works in IE10 / 11

Comment: @Notion - There's no value in "one line" (and if you use `val`, on its own, as you have in your comment, you need that first line regardless.) If you want IE10 (!??!!) or IE11 support, just use `var` instead of `const`.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript both the value `undefined` and empty strings are considered **falsy** and will evaluate as **false** if used as boolean arguments.
You can use this behaviour to create very simple null checks with some parentheses.

```js
w = ($('#x').val() || '').slice(3,5) || 0;
```

This code will first add an undefined/null safe check to your `$(...).val()` operation using a logical or operation ( `||` ). So if there is no value to be found, then an empty string will be returned instead.

Once this has been done the slice will be applied to either the value or an empty string. If the result from the slice is an empty string then a `0` is returned instead.

Please be advised that in your initial example you are also attempting to address the variable `x` instead of using `$('#x')`. These are not interchangeable unless you first assign `var x = $('#x')`.

Comment: will this work in IE 11 or IE10 also?

Comment: @Notion - Yes, none of this is anything new.

Comment: Yes, you can use this example with IE10+. IE will evaluate all of these correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var w;
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var x = $("#x").val();
    w = (x !== undefined || x.length >= 4 ? x.slice(3, 5) : "0");
    console.log(w);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="x"> <button id="btn">Go</buton>
</div>
```

This checks is `x` is `undefined` or if the length of the String is long enough be sliced.